# Azure oAuth token retrieval with user managed identity

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure. I have an app service and a system managed and an user managed identity.  I want to use the rest endpoint to get the access tokens. Based on a config flag, I want to use either

1. Use the User Managed Identity to get the access tokens. or
2. Use the system managed identity to get the access tokens.

Since I am new, I am not sure about which endpoint to call. Most importantly, I want to under as to how I can request the AAD to use User Managed Identity over the system managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one **App service** where I enabled system assigned managed identity like below:

[image]

Now, Open **Kudu** by selecting `Advanced Tools` in your App Service like below:

[image]

In new tab, **Kudo** will be opened where you need to select `PowerShell` under **Debug console** like below:

[image]

Now, run the below PowerShell script to get access token using **System-assigned managed identity**:

```
$resourceURI = "https://storage.azure.com"
$tokenAuthURI = $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&api-version=2019-08-01"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"X-IDENTITY-HEADER"="$env:IDENTITY_HEADER"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can run **`$accessToken`** to print the token like below:

[image]

I added one **user managed identity** to the App Service like below:

[image]

To get access token using **User assigned Managed Identity**, you need to include one of the **optional** parameters like `client_id` or
`principal_id` in the script.

You can find **values** of these parameters from your managed identity:

[image]

In my case, I included **`client_id`** in PowerShell script to get token using **User assigned managed identity** like below:

```
$resourceURI = "https://storage.azure.com/"
$client_id = "d5845093-6622-4827-ad6a-xxxxxxxxxx"
$tokenAuthURI = $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&client_id=$client_id&api-version=2019-08-01"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"X-IDENTITY-HEADER"="$env:IDENTITY_HEADER"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can run **`$accessToken`** to print the token like below:

[image]

Based on your requirement, you can change the value of **`$resourceURI`** parameter to https://graph.microsoft.com,
https://vault.azure.net or https://management.azure.com etc...

Including one of the **optional** parameters is enough to get access token from User Managed Identity over the system managed.

**Reference:**
[Managed identities - Azure App Service | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Cpowershell#connect-to-azure-services-in-app-code)

Comment: Thanks, thats sounds about right and I am trying the same, I dont see your clientId being used in the example's you have given here. could you please update? when you say add Client id as param. is it query, path or header param, that is not clear.

Comment: `Client_id` is **query** parameter. You can check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Cpowershell#rest-endpoint-reference) to know more in detail.

Comment: $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&api-version=2019-08-01" can you update your answer with the query parameter please?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I missed adding `client_id` in token endpoint. Please check the **updated** answer.